# Quel est le substantif associé à l'adjectif « désabusé » ?

Tags: sens, noms, substantivation

Je cherche le nom commun décrivant le fait d'*être désabusé*.
Le nom pour le verbe *abuser* est *abus*, mais peut-on parler de *désabus* ?
Un synonyme est *blasé*, mais je cherche vraiment celui-là.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il en existe deux, *désabus*, trop rare pour apparaître dans les dictionnaires et le plus lourd *[désabusement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sabusement)*.

**Désabus** fut le premier (Sébastien Hardy 1617) à apparaître pour traduire l'espagnol *desengaño*. Il est le plus logique puisqu'il se conforme au schéma **abuser → abus**. Plus tard, c'est *désabusement* (Bouhours 1675) qui a malheureusement eu la faveur de l'Académie française.

Aujourd'hui, aucun de ces deux mots n'est d'usage courant mais les deux se rencontrent parfois.

Comment: qu'entendez-vous par "trop rare pour apparaître dans le dictionnaire" ? Est-ce un mot qui a disparu de l'usage courant ou persiste-t-il dans un contexte particulier?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Un mot qui n'est pas dans le dico est-il officiellement incorrect ?

Comment: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/désabusement

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Désabus est « dans le dico ». Il apparaît dans la définition de « [Faichier](http://www.definistaire.org/dictionnaire-des-mots-qui-n-existent-pas/faichier-232) », mot du « dictionnaire des mots qui n'existent pas » ;-)

Comment: @Simon Il y a plusieurs dictionnaires reconnus et il arrive qu’on ne trouve certains mots que dans l’un d’entre-eux.